# How to filter data in dataview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to filter data on the textchange event on listview so I use dataview to filter data. Issue in the below code is,  I use dataview inside for each so that it checks only one condition that is last value only it takes, I want to check value in **s1** with dataview and remaining value should bind with listview.

eg: if I type **an** in textbox it should list all the item values starting with an value like anandha kumar,anna ect. suppose I keep the value anandha kumar and anna in array s1. I should list all other values expect the array values like antony ect... in listview.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dvProducts = (DataView)Session["ListViewItems"];

            string serachText = EscapeLikeValue(TextBox1.Text);

            string lvValues = hdRetailCustomerGroup.Value;

            string trim = lvValues.Replace(" ", "");

            trim = trim.Replace("\r", "");

            trim = trim.Replace("\n", "");

            trim = trim.Replace("\t", "");
             string str = trim;

            string[] list = str.Split('|');


            foreach (string s1 in list)
            {
                if (s1 != string.Empty)
                {
                    dvProducts.RowFilter = "(CODE like '" + serachText + "*') AND (CODE <> '" + s1 + "')";
                    Session["ListViewItems"] = dvProducts;
                }
            }

                       ListView1.DataSource = dvProducts;
                     ListView1.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the results and want to show the final output ?

Answer (score 21):

```
DataView view = new DataView();
view.Table = DataSet1.Tables["Suppliers"];
view.RowFilter = "City = 'Berlin'";
view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;
view.Sort = "CompanyName DESC";

// Simple-bind to a TextBox control
Text1.DataBindings.Add("Text", view, "CompanyName");
```

Ref:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

Comment: i gave view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent; i shows empty dataview. I want to omit the s1 value in dataview

Comment: view.RowFilter = "City != 'Berlin'";

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
Datatable newTable = new DataTable();
foreach (string s1 in list)
{
   if (s1 != string.Empty)
   {
      dvProducts.RowFilter = "(CODE like '" + searchText + "*') AND (CODE <> '" + s1 + "')";
      foreach (DataRow dr in dvProducts.ToTable().Rows)
      {
         newTable.ImportRow(dr);
      }
   }
}
ListView1.DataSource = newTable;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Check this link and format list view according to your own,           http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx

Comment: it also get overwriting. i want to omit the s1 values in dataview and stored in some table

Comment: Then create new datatable and add the rows,

Comment: I have modified Above Code, Try it