# How I can filter a Datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, datatable, dataset

I use a DataTable with Information about Users and I want search a user or a list of users in this DataTable. I try it butit don't work :(

Here is my c# code:

```
 public DataTable GetEntriesBySearch(string username,string location,DataTable table)
        {
            list = null;
            list = table;

            string expression;
            string sortOrder;

            expression = "Nachname = 'test'";
            sortOrder = "nachname DESC";

            DataRow[] rows =  list.Select(expression, sortOrder);

            list = null; // for testing
            list = new DataTable(); // for testing

            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                list.ImportRow(row);
            }

            return list; 
        }
```

Comment: is the code working or do you get any error?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an exception or do you get 0 results (2 different things)?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can use DataView.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(yourDatatable);
dv.RowFilter = "query"; // query example = "id = 10"
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Comment: exactly what I needed!  thanks for the example link!

Answer (score 140):

If you're using at least .NET 3.5, i would suggest to use `Linq-To-DataTable` instead since it's much more readable and powerful:

```
DataTable tblFiltered = table.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(row => row.Field<String>("Nachname") == username
                   &&   row.Field<String>("Ort") == location)
          .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<String>("Nachname"))
          .CopyToDataTable();
```

Above code is just an example, actually you have [many more methods available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx).

Remember to add `using System.Linq;` and for the `AsEnumerable` extension method a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` dll ([How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006757/how-to-add-a-reference-to-system-data-datasetextensions-to-a-web-site-ascx-cs-fi)).

Comment: Note of caution - CopyToDataTable() copies the datarows. This is not a clone operation, so some of the properties from the original table are not copied across e.g. table name

Comment: @Tim: What about the performance point of view of this code? Is it better to store in some object list and then apply linq/lambda?

Comment: @RajeshMishra: if you already have a filled `DataTable` keep it. Otherwise i would prefer a `List<CustomClass>` because you have no boxing/unboxing. A `DataTable` uses `System.Object` for everything so you always have to cast. Having a custom class with meaningful properties has also many more advantages apart from readability.

Comment: Note that you may get the error `The source contains no DataRows` which can be avoided like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324740/the-source-contains-no-datarows#28324802

Comment: @SharpC: from a performance point of view it would be better to use `try...catch` and handle the `InvalidOperationException` instead of using `if(rows.Any())...` because you execute the query twice otherwise.

Answer (score 22):

use it:

```
.CopyToDataTable()
```

example:

```
string _sqlWhere = "Nachname = 'test'";
string _sqlOrder = "Nachname DESC";

DataTable _newDataTable = yurDataTable.Select(_sqlWhere, _sqlOrder).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Can you explain with a bit more detail why this is an answer to the question asked?

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes you actually want to return a `DataTable` than a `DataView`. So a `DataView` was not good in my case and I guess few others would want that too. Here is what I used to do

```
myDataTable.select("myquery").CopyToDataTable()
```

This will filter `myDataTable` which is a DataTable and return a new `DataTable`

Hope someone will find that is useful

Comment: This will fail if the select query returned no results.

Answer (score 11):

For anybody who work in VB.NET (just in case)

```
Dim dv As DataView = yourDatatable.DefaultView

dv.RowFilter ="query" ' ex: "parentid = 0"
```

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use DataView for this task.

Example of the using it you can find in this post: [How to filter data in dataview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009675/how-to-filter-data-in-dataview)

Answer (score 2):

Hi we can  use ToLower Method sometimes it is not filter.

```
EmployeeId = Session["EmployeeID"].ToString();
var rows = dtCrewList.AsEnumerable().Where
   (row => row.Field<string>("EmployeeId").ToLower()== EmployeeId.ToLower());

   if (rows.Any())
   {
        tblFiltered = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
   }
```