# Filtering and unfiltering DataTables

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, datatable

I have two listboxes with dataTable datasources.  the first datatable is filled from a database.  the other datatable is filled when a player in the first datatable is selected and a "move" button is clicked.  this move button moves the datarow from datatable one to datatable two.  players can also be moved back to datatable one if a mistake was made or they didn't end up playing.

Datatable one has 4 columns.  PlayerId, shortname, fullname and currentplayer.

When the main form is loaded, I have datatable one populated with DataRows there the currentplayer value is equal to true.  I also have a chkbox on the for that i want to be able to display all player irrelevant of currentplayer value.

is there a way to get a filter working.

Comment: I looked into the DataView suggestion that you gave me.  Worked exactly how i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012660/1339616 
You can also use the datatable "Select" command with parameters for filtering and sorting:

```
datatable.Select(filterExp, sortExp, rowstatevalue).
```

See this post http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_filter_sort.html and this one from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Took a look at the first link you posted and saw it mentioned DataView as did Grants comment.  Dug a bit deeper as to what and how to use DataView and it works great.  Thanks guys..