# ReportViewer with DataTable don't applies DataView

Tags: c#, datatable, reportviewer, rdlc, dataview

This is my first post here so please excuse me if I do something wrong.

My question is really simple but it's like I stand in front of a wall...i just try to filter the data of my DataTable that I have created in my DataSet. I use the DataSet to fill my .rdlc report, this works good.

But now I want to filter the data in the DataTable by the Date Column (in my SQL Express it is named Datum and a nchar(10) column, it's not the best idea and I should change it i know ;) ).

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012585/how-i-can-filter-a-datatable) and [this very usefull site](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) and created my samplecode in base of this two sites but the data isn't filtered. I think i could have forgot something...

Here is my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dvDay = new DataView(this.dsStempelJoinsTests.dtJOIN);
        dvDay.RowFilter = "Datum = '12.03.2014'";
        this.dtJOINTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsStempelJoinsTests.dtJOIN);

        this.rvData.RefreshReport();
    }
```

The Data in my SQL Express is stored like this 31.02.2014. But my .rdlc report shows data from other dates.

Comment: I haven't used ADO.Net for a while but I guess you need to Fill the adapter view the view: this.dtJOINTableAdapter.Fill(dvDay);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sort` in your SQL Query here is an example how you can do this.  e.g

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country ASC;
```