# How to add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions to a Web Site ascx.cs file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

We're working with a Web Site project and trying to reference `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. (Using a Web Application would be better; the technical lead, though, has her reasons.)

Here is what we have tried:

1. Find the assembly path.
2. Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and run `sn.exe -T "full\path.dll"`
3. Add the following to the web.config based on the Public key token.

web.config > system.web >

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <!-- Other assemblied omitted -->
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, 
        Version=4.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

The full path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`

Despite this, msbuild still complains when we add `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to a code behind file. What gives? How do we solve this?

Answer (score 4):

## Short Answer

The problem was our `using` statement. So, there were two requirements.

1. Reference `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` in the web.config file. (See below for finding the full assembly name.)
2. Add a `using` statement for `System.Data` in the C# file.

The problem was that our using statement was for `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

## Explanation

[Rick Strahl explains](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/May/04/Adding-Default-Assemblies-Namespaces-and-Control-Prefixes-in-WebConfig) that by default ASP.NET includes:

- all assemblies in the `bin` path
- any GAC-based assembly references in the web.config `<compilation>` section

Further, we were able to query to GAC from a Visual Studio Command Prompt as follows:

```
> gacutil /l System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.17929
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Number of items = 2
```

This confirmed that the assembly we wanted was in the GAC. It also listed the full name of the assembly that we needed to reference in the web.config file.

Comment: *We needed to copy the assembly to the bin not to reference it in the web.config.* This seems the wrong solution.

Comment: @xanatos Why does this seem the wrong solution? What is the alternative? I lack experience with web site projects.

Comment: There must be some problem in the configuration file... But I do know that copying Microsoft assemblies in the bin folder isn't a right solution.

Comment: @xanatos Thank you for your feedback. It turned out that the problem wasn't with the web.config file but in the way that we were doing the `using` statement.