# WPF DataGrid filter. Searching parts of a cell text, not exact content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid and a textbox where the user will introduce a text to filter, but right now only filters identical texts. I mean, if the row text is "ABCDE" and the users writes in the filter textbox "ABCDE" it will appear. If the user writes "ABCD" it won't. I want the filter to show all matches with "ABCD", for example "XAGABCDA" or "ABCDEGFA" not only the ones that are exactly "ABCD".

I have this simple code:

```
private static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.***.0.***; User Id=sa;Password=***; Initial Catalog=***");
private static SqlCommand myCmdE = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM COMPAINES_EXT", con);
private static SqlDataAdapter daE = new SqlDataAdapter(myCmdE);
private static DataTable dtE = new DataTable("COMPAINES_EXT");
IBindingListView blvE = dtE.DefaultView;

public void Load() //this fills the DataGrid "dataGridE"
{
        daE.Fill(dtE);
        dataGridE.ItemsSource = dtE.DefaultView;
}             

private void btn_filtrarE_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        dataGridE.DataContext = dtE;
        blvE.Filter = cmb_FiltrarE.Text + " = '" + txt_filtrarE.Text + "'";
}

//this filters using the column names already written in the combobox cmb_FiltrarE and looks for the text written in the textbox txt_filtrarE
```

Is there anyway that the `IBindingListView` allows me to search letters or words and not the exact content of the cell? I don't want to use loops.

Maybe there's a different but efficient way to do it, it would be great too.

Comment: if I remember correct, syntax is similar to t-sql: `blvE.Filter = cmb_FiltrarE.Text + " like '%" + txt_filtrarE.Text + "%'";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can filter a Datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012585/how-i-can-filter-a-datatable)