# How can I filter data with Dataview when column name include "-" type of character

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable, dataview

My table has three columns(`NIGHTS`,`CRUISE-ID`,`DEP-DATE`).I found a way to filter data table like this.(this link help a lot :[Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012585/how-i-can-filter-a-datatable)).

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
 dv.RowFilter = "NIGHTS=7";//query
```

this works fine and filtered data correctly.but when I use to filter like below

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
     dv.RowFilter = "CRUISE-ID=2K2KFJDKF"; //query
```

It only reads `CRUISE` string from the `query` and gives an error.How can I filtered for `CRUISE-ID`.hope your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter

> Column names
>
> If a column name contains any of these special characters ~ ( ) # \ /
>   = > < + **-** * % & | ^ ' " [ ], you must enclose the column name within square brackets [ ]. If a column name contains right bracket ] or
>   backslash \, escape it with backslash (] or \).

Thus the code would be:

```
 dv.RowFilter = "[CRUISE-ID]='2K2KFJDKF'"; //query
```

Comment: I tried like this `dv.RowFilter = "[CRUISE-ID]=AX20160423GOAGOA";`,but it gives this error `{"Cannot find column [AX20160423GOAGOA]."}`

Comment: Would that have to include single quotes, like `"[CRUISE-ID]='AX20160423GOAGOA'"`?

Comment: is it possible to check `!=` not equal queries also, I mean `NIGHTS != 7`

Comment: According to the linked page in the 'comparison operators' section, yes: it would be `dv.RowFilter = "NIGHTS <> 7" `