# Filter data within `datagridview` bounded from `datatable`

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I am trying to filter data within `datagridview` bounded from `data table` as below on the `exchange` event, but when I clear all data from `datagridview` does not 
return to it is original data (I mean without filters) all it shows is the last 
data filtered

one last question is the filter using the LINQ method in this [link answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012585/how-i-can-filter-a-datatable/13012660#13012660) is better than the one I use?

**because I have around 7 `textbox` use as filters**

```
    private void TB_FirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_FirstName.Text))
        {
            (DGV_SearchResult.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("NAM LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstName.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Best insert a BindingSource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the filter, you should set `RowFilter` property to `string.Empty` or null:

```
private void TB_FirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = DGV_SearchResult.DataSource as DataTable;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_FirstName.Text))
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("NAM LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstName.Text);
    else
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an else to rebind the data source once the textbox is empty something like

```
private void TB_FirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_FirstName.Text))
        {
            (DGV_SearchResult.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("NAM LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstName.Text);
        }
    else
        { 
           // Load data again
        }
}
```