# Filter the data binding source

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox bound to a data binding source using Microsoft access ,a label and a button.

What I want to do is when user type a word in textbox and click the button, label would show the binding value.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            textBox1.Focus();

            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a word");
            }
            else if ( // Filter the word // )
            {
               // Result in the label //
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Word not found");
            }     
        }
```

I have seen a similar code but it is in different language
The code I have seen :

```
If
  dictBindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID, 'Sysem.String') LIKE '" & textBox1.Text & "')" &
                "OR (Word LIKE '" & textBox1.Text & "' )"
```

Comment: Label1.Text = Textbox1.Text This will make the label show the text the user typed in the text box.

Comment: I mean Eg ." A" is bound to "Apple" in data source .
When the user type "A" in the textbox and click the button,
Label would show "Apple" .

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are binding the control to the binding source.

Comment: If you are using a DataTable, it would be something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012585/how-i-can-filter-a-datatable

Comment: Is MessageBox your label? Or a different control not featured here? We might need to see the markdown as well.